# console java wizard framework?

Tags: java

I want to create console wizard (analog of already existent UI wizard for those users who do not have X-server installed).
That should be something like:

```
Select language: [E] English [I] Italian [R] Russian
```

Can I use some kind of library for that or this is so simple that I should write it myself from scratch?

Answer (score 3):

The [Charva project](http://www.pitman.co.za/projects/charva/index.html) might be close to what you are looking for.

It renders a full Java GUI in nothing but ASCII characters.

Here are a few [screenshots](http://www.pitman.co.za/projects/charva/Screenshots.html).